# Honeyminer Error?

Tags: monero-mining

I'm new to this and am wondering if this is something I can fix or that it is just my mac.

I have HoneyMiner running on my mac. It seems to be running however if I check the logs it gives me the following error.

`Monero miner (HoneyMiner_XM) halted by external program`

I can't seem to find what the external program is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mine Monero you'll need to use a miner that actually supports the latest Monero hashing algorithm, RandomX. See XMRig.

Comment: Allright. Thnx. Gonna check that out!